# How to disable and enable reactivity in shiny modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to find a way to disable reactivity of the recently generated output but enable reactivity for the current output that is being rendered.

In this example, I click `New` to start a new plot and choose inputs. Then, I click `New` again which creates a new plot below the first plot. However, when I change the inputs, all the output plots change. I only want the current new plot to change.

To solve this issue I would like to click the `New` button which disables reactivity of the old plot but keeps reactivity enabled for the current new plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

scatter_plot <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  
  x <- rlang::sym(xvar)
  y <- rlang::sym(yvar)
  
  p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
          axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.1)))
  
  return(p)
  
}


regress <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  
  # lefts <- rlang::sym(xvar)
  # rights <- rlang::sym(yvar)
  
  lefts <- xvar
  rights <- yvar
  
  lefts <- paste(lefts, " ~ ")
  rights <- paste(rights, collapse = " + ")
  
  formula <- paste(lefts, rights)
  
  r <- summary(lm(formula, data = dataset))
  
  return(r)
}

importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
    #   tableOutput(ns("contents"))
  )
  
}

importSE <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 dtreact <- reactive({
                   file <- input$file1
                   if (is.null(file))
                     return(NULL)
                   read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                 })
                 
                 
                 output$contents <- renderTable({
                   dtreact()
                 })
                 
                 return(dtreact)
               }
  )
  
}

varselect_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  var_choices <- ""
  tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
          selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL))
}

varselect_server <- function(id, dataset) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 observeEvent(dataset(), {
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "xvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "yvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                 })
                 
                 return(
                   list(
                     xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
                     yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
                   )
                 )
               }
  )
}

regselect_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  var_choices <- ""
  tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
          selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE))
}

regselect_server <- function(id, dataset) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 observeEvent(dataset(), {
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "xvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                   updateSelectInput(session,
                                     "yvar",
                                     choices = names(dataset()))
                 })
                 
                 return(
                   list(
                     xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
                     yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
                   )
                 )
               }
  )
}
scatterplot_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("plot1"))
  
}

scatterplot_server <- function(id, dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 plot1_obj <- reactive({
                   req(dataset())
                   p <- scatter_plot(dataset(), xvar = xvar(), yvar = yvar())
                   return(p)
                 })
                 
                 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                   plot1_obj()
                 })
               }
  )
}


regressUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  verbatimTextOutput(ns("regout"))
}


regressSE <- function(id, dataset, xvar, yvar) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 reg_obj <- reactive({
                   req(dataset())
                   r <- regress(dataset(), xvar = xvar(), yvar = yvar())
                   return(r)
                 })
                 
                 output$regout <- renderPrint({
                   reg_obj()
                 })
               })
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(selectInput(inputId = "input1", label = NULL, choices = c(" ", "Import", "Select", "Regress"))),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Import'", importUI("import")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Select'", actionButton("run1", "New"), varselect_ui("select")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Regress'", actionButton("run2", "New "), regselect_ui("select1"))),
    
    mainPanel(div(id = "add_here"))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dataset <- importSE("import")
  
  df <- dataset
  
  plotvars <- varselect_server("select", dataset = dataset)
  
  plotvars2 <- regselect_server("select1", dataset = dataset)
  
  
  
  
  #  regressSE("regress1", dataset = df, xvar = plotvars2$xvar, yvar = plotvars2$yvar)
  
 #  output$contents <- renderTable({
 #    dataset()
 #  })
  
  counter <- 1
  
  observeEvent(input$run1, {
    current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
    
    scatterplot_server(id = current_id,
                   dataset = df, 
                   xvar = plotvars$xvar,
                   yvar = plotvars$yvar)
    
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", 
             ui = scatterplot_ui(current_id))
    
    
    counter <<- counter + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$run2, {
    current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
    
    r <- regressSE(id = current_id,
                   dataset = df, 
                   xvar = plotvars2$xvar,
                   yvar = plotvars2$yvar)
    
    output$out <- renderPrint({
      r
    })
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_here", 
             ui = regressUI(current_id))
    
    
    counter <<- counter + 1
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, changing the input changes all the output. But I want only the second output to change based on the input.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to solve the issue, but need to know how many plots are you expecting to be made?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @MritiAgarwal. I would like to create an arbitrary or unlimited number of plots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the current plot ID in a `reactiveVal` in the main `server` function and supply that reactive value as parameter to the module. The module can then compare the ID it got on creation with the current ID and update the plot only when the two IDs match.

The code for the whole thing is below. (I have added only few lines- each highlighted with a "NEW" comment.) You can get a nice overview of the changes in the RStudio Document outline:
[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

scatter_plot <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
    
    x <- rlang::sym(xvar)
    y <- rlang::sym(yvar)
    
    p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = !!x, y = !!y)) +
        geom_point() +
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
              axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.1)))
    
    return(p)
    
}


regress <- function(dataset, xvar, yvar) {
    
    # lefts <- rlang::sym(xvar)
    # rights <- rlang::sym(yvar)
    
    lefts <- xvar
    rights <- yvar
    
    lefts <- paste(lefts, " ~ ")
    rights <- paste(rights, collapse = " + ")
    
    formula <- paste(lefts, rights)
    
    r <- summary(lm(formula, data = dataset))
    
    return(r)
}

importUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
        fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
        checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
        #   tableOutput(ns("contents"))
    )
    
}

importSE <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                     
                     dtreact <- reactive({
                         file <- input$file1
                         if (is.null(file))
                             return(NULL)
                         read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                     })
                     
                     
                     output$contents <- renderTable({
                         dtreact()
                     })
                     
                     return(dtreact)
                 }
    )
    
}

varselect_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    var_choices <- ""
    tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
            selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL))
}

varselect_server <- function(id, dataset) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                     observeEvent(dataset(), {
                         updateSelectInput(session,
                                           "xvar",
                                           choices = names(dataset()))
                         updateSelectInput(session,
                                           "yvar",
                                           choices = names(dataset()))
                     })
                     
                     return(
                         list(
                             xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
                             yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
                         )
                     )
                 }
    )
}

regselect_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    var_choices <- ""
    tagList(selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Select X variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL),
            selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Select Y variable", choices = var_choices, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE))
}

regselect_server <- function(id, dataset) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                     observeEvent(dataset(), {
                         updateSelectInput(session,
                                           "xvar",
                                           choices = names(dataset()))
                         updateSelectInput(session,
                                           "yvar",
                                           choices = names(dataset()))
                     })
                     
                     return(
                         list(
                             xvar = reactive({input$xvar}),
                             yvar = reactive({input$yvar})
                         )
                     )
                 }
    )
}
scatterplot_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    plotOutput(ns("plot1"))
    
}

########## NEW parameter 'active_plot_id' in function##########
scatterplot_server <- function(id, dataset, xvar, yvar, active_plot_id) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                     
                     plot1_obj <- reactive({
                         
                         ########## NEW check if IDs match##########
                         req(id == active_plot_id(), cancelOutput = TRUE)
                         
                         req(dataset())
                         p <- scatter_plot(dataset(), xvar = xvar(), yvar = yvar())
                         return(p)
                     })
                     
                     output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                         plot1_obj()
                     })
                 }
    )
}


regressUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("regout"))
}


regressSE <- function(id, dataset, xvar, yvar) {
    moduleServer(id,
                 function(input, output, session) {
                     
                     reg_obj <- reactive({
                         req(dataset())
                         r <- regress(dataset(), xvar = xvar(), yvar = yvar())
                         return(r)
                     })
                     
                     output$regout <- renderPrint({
                         reg_obj()
                     })
                 })
}



ui <- fluidPage(
    wellPanel(selectInput(inputId = "input1", label = NULL, choices = c(" ", "Import", "Select", "Regress"))),
    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Import'", importUI("import")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Select'", actionButton("run1", "New"), varselect_ui("select")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.input1 == 'Regress'", actionButton("run2", "New "), regselect_ui("select1"))),
        
        mainPanel(div(id = "add_here"))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    dataset <- importSE("import")
    
    df <- dataset
    
    plotvars <- varselect_server("select", dataset = dataset)
    
    plotvars2 <- regselect_server("select1", dataset = dataset)
    
    
    
    
    #  regressSE("regress1", dataset = df, xvar = plotvars2$xvar, yvar = plotvars2$yvar)
    
    #  output$contents <- renderTable({
    #    dataset()
    #  })
    
    
    ########## NEW reactive value to store current id##########
    active_plot_id <- reactiveVal()
    
    counter <- 1
    
    observeEvent(input$run1, {
        current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
        
        ########## NEW update current ID and give reactive value to module##########
        active_plot_id(current_id)
        
        scatterplot_server(id = current_id,
                           dataset = df, 
                           xvar = plotvars$xvar,
                           yvar = plotvars$yvar,
                           active_plot_id = active_plot_id)
        
        
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", 
                 ui = scatterplot_ui(current_id))
        
        
        counter <<- counter + 1
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$run2, {
        current_id <- paste0("out_", counter)
        
        r <- regressSE(id = current_id,
                       dataset = df, 
                       xvar = plotvars2$xvar,
                       yvar = plotvars2$yvar)
        
        output$out <- renderPrint({
            r
        })
        
        insertUI(selector = "#add_here", 
                 ui = regressUI(current_id))
        
        
        counter <<- counter + 1
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is great! Would it be possible to try a nested module solution? For example, is there is a way to go back to the previous plot, make it active, and change the inputs to modify the plot. I would like to see if I can enable reactivity again.

Comment: I think it would suffice to save the previous IDs somewhere and copy the one you'd like to edit again to `active_plot_id ` when needed. Then the respective plot should then be active again. This strategy could certainly also be implemented using nested modules.